# Is this sql query correct? If incorrect how can I fix it?

Tags: sql

Schema:

```
Student(studentid,name,age)
Course(coursename,dept)
enroll(studentid,course,grade)
```

I need to find , for students in each age group find their average grade for courses they have taken for Political Science and History, and return the names of student with max average grade for each age group

My attempt so far is :

```
select max(grade), age, name
from (
    select name, age, grade
    from student s, (
            select avg(grade) as grade, e.studentid
            from enroll e
            where dname in ('Political Sciences', 'History')
            group by studentid
            ) as temp
    where s.studentid = temp.studentid
) temp1
group by temp1.age;
```

I want to know if logically it is correct, and not syntactically.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few tips regarding your query:

1. Be careful with your table aliases. Make sure that you carry them over to your `SELECT`
2. You can only include columns in your `SELECT` that are being used in your aggregate (`GROUP BY`). Therefore, you can't `GROUP BY temp1.age` and `SELECT age, name`

Comment: True, needs to add temp1.name to that last `group by`. (I wasn't looking too closely at the syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind your SQL looks solid to me, so long as "Age" correlates to "Age Group", and does not refer to the individual student's age.